# What's a wind is blowing In the direction North meaning?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

What's the different between "wind blowing IN" and "wind blowing FROM"?

Comment: +1 I always get confused by these even though I'm a native speaker. Also "wind is in the north", "wind is north at 5 knots", "wind is to the north", and "wind is at the north".

Comment: Complete sentences using these phrases would make the difference easier to explain.

Answer (score 2):

A wind blowing *in the direction of* the north means blowing towards the north (the wind is heading north).

A wind blowing *from the north* means it is coming from the north (and heading south).

A wind blowing *in the north* means that in the northern part of the country (or the world, or whatever the frame of reference is) there is a wind blowing (that could be in any direction).

Answer (score -1):

A wind blowing IN from the North means the wind is travelling North to South, also referred to as a "northerly wind".

A wind blowing FROM the north is essentially the same thing.

Omegastick is correct that if it was phrased "A wind blowing in the direction of the north" means it is blowing south to north, but to my knowledge this phrase would never be used.  In from/from are overwhelmingly more common, as are northerly/southerly and so on.

Note that the "northerly" examples only refer to wind - e.g. a northerly wind means it is travelling from north to south, but if you referred to say a person travelling in a northerly direction it would mean the opposite, that they are heading north.

Comment: Please add a comment if you're going to downvote a correct answer.